# getting two camera preview with raspberry pi compute module

Tags: python, camera, raspicam, compute-module-3

You know raspberry pi compute module has two CSI camera inputs. I can connect two camera and activate both of them. I have a project with raspberry pi that I need to preview from both camera simultaneously and seperately. picamera (python lib) has options only stereoscopic view in one window by two cameras. Is there any solution about it ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be able to pull this off by creating separate device nodes for each camera using uv4l. There's a walkthrough [here on linux-projects.org](https://www.linux-projects.org/uv4l/tutorials/dual-cameras/), which suggests that running the following commands should allow you to 'access them individually through /dev/video0 and /dev/video1 with any Video4Linux2-complaint application'. They've applied their own encoding settings to the nodes, but you should be able to tweak those to whatever you need.

```
uv4l --driver raspicam --auto-video_nr --encoding=h264 --width=1280 --height=768 --camera-number=0

uv4l --driver raspicam --auto-video_nr --encoding=mjpeg --width=640 --height=480 --camera-number=1 --server-option='--port=9000'
```